# Identify uncorrelated variables from a Spearman's matrix using cut-off thresholds

Tags: r, correlation

I have undertaken a Spearman's rank correlation coefficient analysis in R: I have successfully plotted/visualised the correlation matrix and exported the matrix table as a csv file.

```r
corr <- cor(q.dat.cor, y = NULL, use = "everything", method = c("spearman"))
    
# corrplot visualisation
install.packages("corrplot")
library(corrplot)
    
# rcorr() computes the p-value 
rcorr <- rcorr(corr)    
    
ggcorr(corr, method = c("pairwise", "spearman"),
       nbreaks = 9.1,
       label = TRUE,
       label_size = 3,
       color = "grey50")
```

My next task is to identify uncorrelated variables so that I can use them later for a cluster analysis, but I need the values to fall between a cut-off threshold (r>0.8 and r>-0.8).

Comment: When 2 variables are highly correlated (`abs(r>0.8)`), do you want to keep one of the two variables or do you want to remove them both?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the future, please make sure to provide an example of your data so that we can produce your current results and make examples that will work with your data. Additionally, you posted a bunch of code that computed the correlation with different packages but (a) didn't load the packages so we didn't know which we need to run your code and (b) it's not clear why we need all of these different approaches here for **what you asked for**.

Comment: Why do you give the `ggcorr` code? Is this a plot issue? What's your expected output?

Comment: Good morning all! I'm sorry for not providing more information to help answer my questions. Thank you for your comments and suggestions, and taking the time to help me. Here are my responses to the following questions:
I would like to keep both of the variables. 
I will provide example data for my future questions to make it more clear what I am asking
The issue was not with plotting, so I now know I did not need to put it in. Thank you for highlighting this.

Answer (score 0):

In the below solution, I create some example data since you did not provide any, then turn the matrix of rank correlation coefficients into a `data.frame` where each row is a correlation. I then keep only rows of the `data.frame` with correlations falling within a specified value range.

I provide two different approaches to removing the non-qualifying rows:

1. Each bivariate correlation appears in two rows: one for `cor(var1, var2)` and one for `cor(var2, var1)`.
2. Each bivariate correlation appears in one row: only one of `cor(var1, var2)` or `cor(var2, var1)` will appear.

Note that while there are simpler ways to do some of the filtering and manipulation with the aid of packages, I provided a solution that is almost entirely using `base` R to not add the complexity of learning a package while also learning how objects and data manipulation work in R.

```r
# Packages
library(Hmisc)
library(tidyr)

# Example data: 3 variables
set.seed(123)
x1 <- rnorm(10)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(10, 0, 1)
x3 <- runif(10)

# Generate spearman's correlation matrix
out <- rcorr(cbind(x1, x2, x3), type = "spearman")
print(out$r)
#>            x1         x2        x3
#> x1  1.0000000  0.7575758 -0.430303
#> x2  0.7575758  1.0000000 -0.600000
#> x3 -0.4303030 -0.6000000  1.000000

# Convert to data.frame with row names as a column
df <- as.data.frame(out$r)
df$var1 <- rownames(df)

# Reshape to long data structure
df_long <- pivot_longer(data = df, 
                        cols = starts_with("x"),
                        names_to = "var2",
                        values_to = "estimate")

print(df_long)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   var1  var2  estimate
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 x1    x1       1    
#> 2 x1    x2       0.758
#> 3 x1    x3      -0.430
#> 4 x2    x1       0.758
#> 5 x2    x2       1    
#> 6 x2    x3      -0.6  
#> 7 x3    x1      -0.430
#> 8 x3    x2      -0.6  
#> 9 x3    x3       1

# Keep only rows where the correlation P is: upper > P > lower
lower <- 0.3
upper <- 1.0

# You could modify the code below to keep only those where estimate
# is greater than upper by using df_long$estimate > upper. The same
# logic of simply flipping the > or < sign also would apply for getting
# the sufficiently extreme negative values too!
keepers <- df_long[df_long$estimate > lower & df_long$estimate < upper, ]

print(keepers)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   var1  var2  estimate
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 x1    x2       0.758
#> 2 x2    x1       0.758

# If you only want one row per bivariate correlation, you can repeat the above
# while setting the lower/upper triangle of the correlation matrix to NA

# Convert to data.frame with row names as a column
out$r[lower.tri(out$r, diag = TRUE)] <- NA 
df <- as.data.frame(out$r)
df$var1 <- rownames(df)

# Reshape to long data structure
df_long <- pivot_longer(data = df, 
                        cols = starts_with("x"),
                        names_to = "var2",
                        values_to = "estimate")

keepers <- df_long[df_long$estimate > lower & 
                     df_long$estimate < upper &
                     !is.na(df_long$estimate), ]

print(keepers)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   var1  var2  estimate
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 x1    x2       0.758
```